# How to access an "inaccessable" input field by selenium in python (bet365)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In order to create a tool for simplifying my own sport bets I would like to automatically fill out the stake and click on "place bet". I already managed so far to automatically login and search for certain matches/ bet types and selecting them.

But now the same way of sending e.g. keys to the inputfield in the betslip (here its the Stake) does not work. Please see the following details:

After any kind of bet was selected the betslip is displayed

[image: betslip]

Checking the code gives the below information, the marked area is where I expect a possible interaction

[image: source code]

I've tried all ways of finding an element, by ID, by name, by css selector, by xpath and different provided names in the marked area.

Non of these worked: e.g.

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("Stake")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("stk bs-Stake_TextBox")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("bs-Stake")`

it always give debug info:
**selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element**

Does anyone have another idea how this can be done?

Thanks a lot

**UPDATE (iFrame Structure attached)**

[image: iframe]

Comment: Could you check higher up in the HTML elements and confirm whether or not there is an `iframe` element in the hierarchy? This would definitely be a cause of the exception.

Comment: Yes there is an iframe. Any possibilities then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit to improve accepted answer quality:

If there is an iframe, you need to switch there first. Also the safe way to find dynamically loaded elements is using the "selenium-built in" *wait for condition*.

It is very beneficial to define a function...

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

# function to wait for element presence or interactibility
def wait_for_elem_by_xpath(xp, timer=10, clickable=False):
    # clickable flag adjusts if should the element be clickable
    # labels and such elements won't be clickable hence the default False
    if clickable:
        # wait for element to be clickable
        method = EC.element_to_be_clickable
    else:
        # wait for element presence
        method = EC.presence_of_element_located

    try:
        # wait until the element is found
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, timer).until(method((By.XPATH, xp)))
        return element
    except TimeoutException as ex:
        # if element is not found  in time, you can retry or return False 
        # or you can set a "negative" flag if you expect an element not to be found
        # or just...
        raise ex
```

So later on you can:

```
# wait for iframe presence by element name
iframe = wait_for_elem_by_xpath('//*[@name="bsFrame"]')
# do the switch
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# wait until input field interactible by xpath class name (since placeholder attribute) is dynamic based on interface language
# note the True flag -> instead of element presence, wait completes when the input field is ready to accept text
input_field = wait_for_elem_by_xpath('//input[@class="stk bs-Stake_TextBox"]', True)
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work. I gues it's due to an iframe higher up in the structure (comment of initial post)

Comment: Updated the answer, but since that part of the page layout is unknown, finding the iframe part is not complete.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I've attached the code in my initial post and did the following (tried to two xpath values)
iframe = driver.find_element_by_name("bsFrame")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
input_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Stake"]').send_keys("10")
input_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Stake']").send_keys("10")
.

Answer (score 3):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()
Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"bsFrame")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@placeholder='Stake']"))).send_keys("test")
```

You need to import followings.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Doesn't work, debug log displays the following:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@placeholder='Stake']"))).send_keys("10")
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Screenshot is always difficult to answer properly however approach is the same if not placeholder try with some other attribute of that element should work.